# blender running so slow i can take a nap when clicking a menu

Tags: particles, performance

I have a big problem. It's been happening for a long time and it's really urgent as this is payed work.

For some reason my project is running so slow I can't even click on the menus. I literally went to bed yesterday after clicking a menu just so it could load in the option to delete it.

I am like 4 days over the deadline and I need urgent help (tell me if you want the packed file, I'm uploading the normal one now, please tell me if you have the same problem as it might be my pc).

Oh  and yes i am working with really big particle systems but even with those completely deleted i get this performance. (for some reason the problems usually start after I have put in something really demanding so it might be that the demanding tasks are still doing the pc from behind even after I've deleted them)

thank you btw for any answers

Comment: Try with another pc, you'll get an answer sooner if you're in a hurry. Be sure to use a powerful one, though. If (?) you upload the file someone else could check but also knowing your machine specs, and blender version, would be needed to understand what could be the issue. Even deleting particles they could still be linked or stay there as orphans, in blender: look for "orphans" in the outliner views

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a memory shortage. Add more physical memory to your machine, reduce the complexity of your meshes and particle systems (when allowed) or pay for an outside cloud rendering service.

In any case, it may be more cost effective to just hard-reboot the machine instead of waiting for the File -> Quit menu to show.  I hate hard crashing my machine, but I'd likely get things rebooted, modified however needed, and running at normal render speed sooner than by shutting down properly.

But first, just in case - check if you're running some other apps at the same time that might be hoarding memory.  Email, web browsers loaded with pages with bad javascript, movie players, another instance of Blender.

Comment: i have 16 gigs atm. and somehow when i finally got to group everything i needed and tried to open it in a different project i no joke had to wait like 4 minutes for the project to load in the append menu

Comment: My power machine at home has 16G.  It would often go slow as you describe. I added a memory/system monitor to show in realtime CPU and memory usage and other stats.  It was enlightening to see how some programs used way more memory, or way less, than I thought.   On Linux, Conky is great.

Comment: yeah i already have that up at all times. blender uses 10 gb at a time and chrome uses like 500 mb and that's all. means i should have a bout 1 gb left on hard loads. the problem here is that even after removing the problematic meshes or systems i still have this problem

Comment: ok so. weird development but i looks lke my ssd is maxing out somehow. my ssd is 100%ing every time i click something

Comment: i might have found the problem. it was some weird mesh error in my ground plain?